# Android Google Maps Api v2 . How get altitude anywhere?

Tags: android, maps, altitude

I want get altitude anywhere my from android phone.

I searching a methods like this way:

{Altitude newAltitude=new Altitude( double latitude,double longitude);}

As a result i will set latitude and longitude then i must get altitude from this (specific) location. I want just Altitude value.

Is there any methods like this.I will use Google Maps Api v2.

Comment: i hope this will help you for beginner.. try tht

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services location libraries give access to the altitude.

Please see:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html